# Не сработает хендлер при импорте

Tags: python, aiogram

друзья, подскажите плз что я делаю не так, есть ситуация:

- Хендлер замечательно работает если поместить сам код в файл bot.py
- Но он не хочет работать когда я ровно этот же код импортирую из файла handlers/all_action.py

Структура проекта:

```
Aggregator/
|    |— handlers/
|   |—— __init__.py
|   |—— all_action.py
|— bot.py
|— config.py
```

Cодержание файла handlers/**init**.py

```
from . import all_action
```

Cодержание файла handlers/all_action.py

```
from aiogram import types
from Agregator.bot import dp
from Agregator import config


@dp.message_handler(commands = "start")
async def first_step(message: types.Message):

    first_step_message = (
        "test")
    await message.answer(first_step_message)
```

Cодержание файла bot.py

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor, filters, types
from config import BOT_TOKEN
import handlers

bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode="Html")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: `@dp.message_handler(commands = "start")`, эта конструкция является декоратором, а `db.message_handler` буквально говорит, что у вас есть объект в `db`, вызови у него функцию `message_handler` и передай в неё декорируемую функцию с параметрами ([простой пример без ботов, чисто на классах](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8c77806ad7950469117287b98dc982e75ebb9549/Decorators__examples/append_handlers.py#L27))

Comment: Т.е. у вас к моменту импорта должен быть создан объект бота, которому и нужно привязать обработчики через декоратор. Советую вам обернуть все обработчики в функцию, в нее явно передавать объект бота, эту функцию можно держать в отдельном файле и импортировать. После импорта создаете бота и вызываете ту функцию, передавая бота ([подобное делал в другой библиотеке ботов](https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/fe66bb4d6b0ae206837341ea15b1a56e03a2bbf7/main.py#L41))

Comment: Благодарю, вероятно проблема как раз в том, что при импорте сначала инициализируются объекты импорта, а затем уже инициализируется то, что находится в файле, в который мы импортируем (bot.py). В этом и была проблема. Решилась выносом объекта dp в отдельный файл и импортом его в (bot.py). Это и решило проблему.

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, самостоятельно ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что хедлеры иницициализировались при ипморте раньше, черз dp (Dispatcher), объект за счет которого мы и обрабатываем эти хенедлеры.

Решение - вынести объект Dispactcher в отдельный файл disp.py c содержанием ниже:

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot
from config import BOT_TOKEN

bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode="Html")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```

Импортировать его в основной файл bot.py

```
from aiogram import executor
from config import BOT_TOKEN
import handlers
from disp import dp, bot

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Dispatcher и хендлеры инициализируются при импорте одновременно, после чего, код заработал. Всем спасибо.